# How to make jquery work in javascript code for html webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, localhost

im writing a website and i cant get my jquery library to work( This is my js code and its not working. Writing in notepad++ with denwer local server

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.sm.plus/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type "text/javascript">
```

Comment: I don't know what CDN that is, but it isn't loading for me.  Try this URL instead:  https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js

Comment: According ot what you show us, you DONT have an javascript or jQuery code

Comment: Also, there's rarely a need for jQuery these days.  If you're building a new project, and you still want to use jQuery, I'd recommend using v3.  3.5.1 is the current version.  Older versions are no longer updated.

Comment: You can start reading the docs: https://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: I am interested @Brad Why do you say there is little need for jQuery

Comment: @RiggsFolly jQuery's primary use case was to normalize all of the various browser APIs for things like selecting elements, XHR, DOM manipulation, etc.  For many years now, these APIs have been standardized.  We have `document.querySelector()`, `fetch()`, `new Promise()`, `el.style`, `el.textContent`, `el.closest()`, etc. etc.  Anecdotally, I used to use jQuery heavily but haven't needed to include it in a project in probably 6 or 7 years.

Comment: @Brad Thanks, thats what I was expecting you to say, but its always useful to have another opinion

Comment: do i need to install it or white another file in local server to use jquery? and if i dont have java how do i get it?) sorry im just a begginer.  btw are you sure this  learn.jquery.com  will work bc its from 2017

Answer (score 1):

Try this script tag instead.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: it works in any local server?? It just doesnt for me? Can it be possible that its not working with my blowser of my Windows?

Comment: Do you see a console error when the local server runs the project? 
Do you see the JS File loaded in the sources? How do you know its not working?